# Screen is black after unplugging battery charger on an Asus k52j

Tags: 13.04, screen, battery

When i unplug my battery charger my screen turns black. I already checked the brightness/battery settings, but nothings is wrong with those settings. Someone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: *using ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Can you add your laptop model to your question? Thanks!

Comment: my laptop model is asus k52j

Comment: I also have it with ubuntu 12.04